# Efficiently find a headSet from a SortedSet in Java

Tags: java, sortedset

In a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), specifically a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), in Java 8 and later, is there a more efficient way to identify a qualifying subset of the first-most elements ("[headSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#headSet-E-)") of elements?

## Scenario

Imagine `Person` objects with a `birthDate` member. We want to exclude minors and leave only adults in our SortedSet.

Or, speaking more technically… I have a collection of objects whose natural ordering (the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) method of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) is based on a date-time value (a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object, or it could be a [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)). I want to delete the older elements that have "[aged-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aging_out)", meaning their date-time value is now less-than my desired date-time.

## Already Sorted

I want to **take advantage of the fact that the elements are already sorted**. So using a [Predicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) with [`removeIf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) in a [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) would be inefficient, as it compares *all* the elements in the SortedSet. Given the sorted order, no need to keep comparing after finding the first mismatch.

## Roll-Your-Own

I suppose I could code a loop myself to find-and-remove, but this seems like something that would be built into the Collections framework.

```
DateTime minimumBirthDateTime = DateTime.now().minusYears( 18 );
SortedSet<Person> persons = … ;
while ( persons.pollFirst() != null ) {
    Person p = persons.first();
    if( p.getBirthDate().isBefore( minimumBirthDateTime ) ) {
        persons.remove( p );  // Remove minors from our SortedSet, leaving only adults.
    }
}
```

## Workaround

**One workaround: Dummy object.**

Construct a fake `Person` object with the minimum birth date-time we want for comparison. Then we can use the nifty methods of the [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface implemented by [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

**Another workaround: Fake subclass, for dummy object.**

Suppose the `Person` class is too complicated in its construction to make a dummy instance. Create a subclass of `Person`, named something like `Person_FakeForSortedSetComparing`. Give that subclass a constructor just for this special purpose. In this example, passing a DateTime object for the minimum birth date.

```
    Person_FakeForSortedSetComparing youngestPossibleAdult = new Person_FakeForSortedSetComparing( minimumBirthDateTime );
    SortedSet<Person> minors = persons.headSet( youngestPossibleAdult );
    persons.removeAll( minors );
```

Comment: You could do a binarny search to find the first item you want to remove.

Comment: Sounds like you want NavigableMap.headMap or tailMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#headMap(K,%20boolean)

Comment: @bhspencer why would you do a logn operation when you could do a constant time operation?

Comment: @SkinnyJ: it's only constant-time if the container implementation maintains the "cut position" on every modification.

Comment: Regarding binary search, be aware than in the [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) implementation of `SortedSet`, just calling `size` is somewhat expensive as it requires a traversal of the elements. We are already sorted, so it should be possible to start comparing at the front and stop when encountering the first mismatch. The class has methods for this, but they require a comparison object in hand which we lack in my case. Perhaps some way to use a stream but interrupt that stream upon encountering a mismatch?

Comment: @PeterLawrey presume you mean the Set versions of those

Comment: @PeterLawrey A `TreeSet` *is* a [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html). The problem with those methods is that they require you have a `Person` object with the minimum allowed birth date value embedded… But we don't have such a `Person`. I cannot construct such a `Person` because the class is too complex to make such a dummy. What we do have is: date-time object of ( today - 18 years ). I need to compare the nested date-time member variable.

Comment: Sounds like it might be better to use a `SortedMap` mapping datetimes to people, then get a headMap. It's like the old question of retrieving an element from a set based on an equal object or enough parts of an object to compute the equality relation. Thinking of this raises another question, though - how are people with the same birthdate ordered?

Comment: "We are already sorted, so it should be possible to start comparing at the front and stop when encountering the first mismatch" - wait, if *that's* good enough for you, why not just use an iterator over the set? `TreeSet` implements `NavigableSet`, so its `iterator` is guaranteed to be ascending. Just call the iterator's `remove` on anything you want to remove until you hit something you don't want to remove, then `break` the loop.

Comment: @user2357112 As I said in the Question, of course I *could* write such a loop but this seems like something that should be possible, perhaps with some clever use of Streams.

Comment: @SkinnyJ In most cases a binary search on a sorted list is going to be faster than a linear search.

Comment: @bhspencer TreeSet is a priority heap, getting the largest element should be constant time, not linear.

Comment: A binary search is just silly when your elements are already sorted, even more so when you know your target elements are at the front grouped together.

Comment: @BasilBourque It sounds like you should be using a TreeMap (note: a TreeSet just wraps a TreeMap) where the key is the details which determine the sort order.  This way creating a distinguishing key should be easy.